# Prove that $I\colon(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_\infty)\to(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_1)$ is not an open map

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, normed-spaces

Deduce that $I\colon(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_\infty)\to(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_1).$ is not an open map.

This question has been resolved previously, but not by this way.

I think that it's sufficient prove is 
$$\exists \gamma >0,\ \exists f\in C[0,1]\text{ such that }B(f,\gamma)\text{ is not open}$$
if we get $g\in C[0,1]$ and $\delta>0$ with:
$$\|f-h\|_{1}<\delta \ \text { and } \ \|f-h\|_\infty \geq \gamma$$
Would somebody give me an idea?

Answer (score 2):

Answering your question about an example (instead of what you asked in the subject):

By letting 
\begin{eqnarray}
f_k(x) &=&\left\{ \begin{matrix} kx & 0<x<\frac{1}{2k}\\ 
1-kx & \frac{1}{2k} \le x \le \frac{1}{k} \\
0& x > \frac{1}{k}\end{matrix} \right.
\end{eqnarray}

You get functions with $||f_k||_\infty = \frac{1}{2}$ but with $||f_k||_1=\frac{1}{4k}$

Answer (score 1):

Sketch: $1/2+x^n \to 1/2$ in the $\|\,\|_1$ norm.  This shows there is a function in the open unit ball in the $\|\,\|_\infty$ norm (namely $1/2$) that is the limit of functions outside that ball (namely $1/2+x^n$)  in the $\|\,\|_1$ norm.